# PHP Will not display errors with display_error setting on in Windows Environment

Tags: php, apache

I am at an impasse, I am trying to turn on error reporting, which until recently was on.

This is a Development environment, completely separated from the Live Environment, The Set up is as follows.
Windows XP Home, 
Apache 2.2,
MySQL 5.0 and PHP 5.2.6

It will run php no problem (Did a phpinfo to ensure that, even shows the mysql db connecting and both the local and master values for display_errors and display_startup_errors are showing as ON)

double checked the PHP.ini file and everything is on and the reporting level is set to E_ALL & E_STRICT

I even tried each of the two individually and rebooted inbetween each attempt.

I even tried setting error_reporting(-1) all to try and figure out where the php script is breaking..

I have looked at all the articles here about the display_errors either wont turn off or on and all point back at the PHP.ini file being the place to be for this. Given I have double checked the entire file for a possible reassignment of values, and there is none.

Is it possible the setting for error reporting is somewhere else as well?

Comment: What have you done to verify that an error condition is triggered?

Comment: can you check if the errors are logged in the error log FILE?

Comment: because its a data migration script and shows whats happening by echoing the queries and resulting data, nothing at all is showing despite numerous echo "<hr>statement $vars<pre>";print_r($expected_arraysnobjects);echo "</pre>";

I checked the error log file and all thats being shown is the favicon.ico file is not being found.

Comment: What happens when you explicitly throw an error in the main script, either via an intentional syntax error or `trigger_error()`?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I even tried a 
'code' trigger_error('No Database Connection', E_USER_ERROR); 'code'

right after the phpinfo statement, the phpinfo shows but the error trigger does not,

I have then also tried 'code' echo (integer) ini_get('display_errors');'code' and get a 1 as a result so the errors should be showing.

I also then checked the .htaccess file and all it does is rewrite the url.

Comment: I am probably sure there is a silly mistake behind this. Make sure you are working on the same directory, check your URL prod/dev ... just the little things.

Comment: After spinning my wheels for a while, I uninstalled the apache and php, ran a complete scan of the system via bootscan and found a babylon rootkit, I removed that and the pair of virus files that seemed to have come from it (Both named babylon in some form or another) then reinstalled the apache and php, got error reporting back, so I suspect it was the rootkit but perhaps will never really know

Comment: oh and for those who are curious, it was a fatal error so the setting of error_reporting would never revealed the error. (Call to an undefined method)

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by looking beyond the usual scenarios and doing a scan of the affected drives, The Systems were firewalled and every security step was taken beforehand, Thankfully it was just the development environment and not the actual production server.

When all else seems to fail, check for viruses and malware in the end I do believe it was the babylon rootkit that was corrupting everything.

Thanks to Gordon, Lea and Sam_io for pointing out stuff that I did take but others may not think of, it was their pointing to the common causes that made me take the unusual steps of uninstalling the php and apache, neither were responsible for data in anyway so made it really easy to restore.